# Model taking long time to train

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, lstm, pytorch

I have added an LSTM layer after a convolution in the VGG-16 model using PyTorch. Overtime, the model learns just fine. However, after adding just one LSTM layer, which consists of 32 LSTM cells, the process of training and evaluating takes about 10x longer.

I added the LSTM layer to a VGG framework as follows

```
def make_layers(cfg, batch_norm=False):
   # print("Making layers!")
    layers = []
    in_channels = 3
    count=0
    for v in cfg:
        count+=1
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        else:
            conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
                in_channels=v
        if count==5:
            rlstm =RLSTM(v)
            rlstm=rlstm.cuda()
            layers+=[rlstm]
```

RLSTM is my custom class, which implements RowLSTM, from Google’s Pixel RNN paper.

Is this a common issue?  Do LSTM layers just take long to train in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since LSTM (and many other RNNs) rely on sequential feeding of information you lose a big portion of parallelization speed ups you generally have with CNNs. There are other types of RNNs you can explore that leverage more parallelizable algorithms but the verdict on their predictive performance compared to LSTM/GRU is still not out

Comment: I'm relatively new to this whole thing: I understand how RNN's are sequential, but what makes CNN's different, which allows them to be parallelizable?

Comment: lets say you have sequence  1 2 3 4 and your CNN is 1 dimensional with filter size 2 - thus it will compute some filter operation F  on inputs (1,2); (2,3); (3,4) resulting in F(1,2); F(2,3); F(3,4) outputs. Notice that all 3 of these can be computed at the same time (parallelized). In RNN context this sequence of outputs would look like F(1);F(F(1),2);F(F(F(1),2),3) ; F(F(F(F(1),2),3),4) - here each consecutive filter is dependent on the previous one making it sequential. Hopefully that makes some sense